# C# Regex extract certain digits from a number

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract the digits from `10:131186;` and get `10131186` without the `:` and `;`.

What is the Regex pattern I need to create?

```
var input = "10:131186;";
string pattern = ":(.*);";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

With the above code, I am getting `:131186;` instead of `10121186`.

Comment: Use string.Replace() than regex...

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to use Regex. It's slower than using `string.Replace` method

```
string input = "10:131186;";
input = input.Replace(":", "");
input = input.Replace(";", "");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Regex.Replace`:

```
var input = "10:131186;";
string pattern = @"(\d+):(\d+);";
string res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1$2");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

and you can also use `Split` with `Join`:

```
var input = "10:131186;";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", input.Split (new char[] { ':', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

```
        string input = "10:131186;";
        input = input.Replace(":", String.Empty).Replace(";", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the group index 1.

```
var input = "10:131186;";
string pattern = ":(.*);";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Value[1]);
```

or use assertions.

```
var input = "10:131186;";
string pattern = "(?<=:).*?(?=;)";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pattern `\\d+` to match digits in the string and concatenate them into a single string.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "10:131186;";
        MatchCollection mCol = Regex.Matches(input, "\\d+");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Match m in mCol)
        {
            sb.Append(m.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
10131186
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9PDr9t)